In Varnish intermittently we are experiencing a high number of incomplete requests. These requests are not connecting to the backend and returing 504
Below type of logs are coming in Varnish access log -- Below type of incomplete logs we are getting at the time of issue:
20241218211542 - - - 0 - Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.6778.108 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; )

also sending  config file of varnish:
# Backend storage specification, see Storage Types in the varnishd(5) # man page for details. 
#VARNISH_STORAGE="malloc,700G"
VARNISH_STORAGE="file,/cache-data/varnish_cache.bin,2750G" 
# User and group for the varnishd worker processes VARNISH_USER=varnish VARNISH_GROUP=varnish
# Other options, see the man page varnishd(1)
DAEMON_OPTS="-p thread_pools=4 -p thread_pool_min=150 -p thread_pool_max=3000 -p thread_pool_timeout=300 -p thread_pool_stack=96k -l 4000M -p timeout_idle=70 -p backend_idle_timeout=300"


Hi Vinay, I'd be happy to assist again, but I'm afraid the information that I requested from you is still missing. I already converted some of your content into preformated text to make it more readable. However, you can probably agree that there's not a lot of useful information in there. So let me recap what I need as a minimum.

Hi Feryn, u have asked out put of below command at the time of issue sudo cat /etc/varnish/default.vcl, sudo systemctl cat varnish, sudo varnishlog -g request -q "", sudo varnishstat -1. However, since this is a production environment and we cannot wait for the issue to occur again,  I'll try to capture above data but it would be great if you can help here. Can I provide these outputs in the current normal condition?

While there isn't enough information available to examine what the root cause of the issue is, I can provide some commands to start the debugging process.
As mentioned by the author of this question:

since this is a production environment and we cannot wait for the issue to occur again

Logging
We do have a timestamp: 20241218211542. This is probably the equivalent of 2024-12-18 21:15:42. If we convert that to a Unix timestamp, we get 1734552942.
We can try to dump all the logs in the VSL buffer and hope the faulty transaction is still captured. Although Varnish comes with a varnishncsa.service unit file for systemd that stores NCSA-style logs in /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log, the full logging transactions are kept in memory for obvious reasons.
If we get lucky the following varnishlog command can give us the right output:
sudo varnishlog -d -g request -q "Timestamp:Start[1] == 1734552942"

The -d option will dump all the content that is stored in VSL's circular memory buffer. And since -l 4000M was set as a runtime parameter, there is 4GB of VSL storage assigned for logs.
And if you want to capture multiple logs in a timeframe of a couple of seconds of that timestamp, maybe you could run the following varnishlog command:
sudo varnishlog -d -g request -q "Timestamp:Start[1] >= 1734552940 and Timestamp:Start[1] <= 1734552959"

This command would capture all logging transactions from 2024-12-18 21:15:40 to 2024-12-18 21:15:59.
While I'm not 100% sure filtering on logstatus zero will work, it doesn't hurt trying to run the following command:
sudo varnishlog -d -g request -q "RespStatus == 0" 

What I'm looking for is a full log transaction that captures this moment where a response is returned with status code zero.
Metrics
While logs paint a very detailed picture, metrics & statistics can provide a broad overview. varnishstat offers a wide range of counters that could expose potential issues.
Please run the following command and add its output to your original question as preformatted text:
sudo varnishstat -1

This will dump all the Varnish metrics. Hopefully it exposes the issue that causes the failures.
Runtime parameters
varnishlog and varnishstat will hopefully tell us more about the issue.
But the ultimate goal is to figure out why the issue is happening (and how we can fix it).
It could be related to misconfigured runtime parameters. Please dump your runtime parameters using the following command:
sudo varnishadm param.show

VCL
An other possibility is that your VCL behavior is causing these issues. Please paste the content of /etc/varnish/default.vcl.
Summary
It's unclear what is going on at this point, but the log item that was shared is our only lead. By collecting logs & metrics, we can figure out what's going on.
It also helps to contextualize the situation by adding VCL config & runtime parameters.
Hopefully Vinay can produce the required output, so we can start digging.

This is Mohit replying on behalf of Vinay

sudo varnishlog -d -g request -q "Timestamp:Start1 == 1734552942"

I Tried searching for different timestamps with above command but could not get any output, will try to search on different paramaters and update again

sudo varnishlog -d -g request -q "RespStatus == 0"

This command is not giving any output

sudo varnishstat -1

Please find output at this link

sudo varnishadm param.show

 accept_filter                 -
    acceptor_sleep_decay          0.9 (default)
    acceptor_sleep_incr           0.000 [seconds] (default)
    acceptor_sleep_max            0.050 [seconds] (default)
    auto_restart                  on [bool] (default)
    backend_idle_timeout          300.000 [seconds]
    backend_local_error_holddown  10.000 [seconds] (default)
    backend_remote_error_holddown 0.250 [seconds] (default)
    ban_cutoff                    0 [bans] (default)
    ban_dups                      on [bool] (default)
    ban_lurker_age                60.000 [seconds] (default)
    ban_lurker_batch              1000 (default)
    ban_lurker_holdoff            0.010 [seconds] (default)
    ban_lurker_sleep              0.010 [seconds] (default)
    between_bytes_timeout         60.000 [seconds] (default)
    cc_command                    exec gcc -std=gnu11 -std=gnu11 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -Wall -Werror -Wno-error=unused-result -pthread -fpic -shared -Wl,-x -o %o %s (default)
    cli_limit                     48k [bytes] (default)
    cli_timeout                   60.000 [seconds] (default)
    clock_skew                    10 [seconds] (default)
    clock_step                    1.000 [seconds] (default)
    connect_timeout               3.500 [seconds] (default)
    critbit_cooloff               180.000 [seconds] (default)
    debug                         none (default)
    default_grace                 10.000 [seconds] (default)
    default_keep                  0.000 [seconds] (default)
    default_ttl                   120.000 [seconds] (default)
    esi_iovs                      10 [struct iovec] (default)
    feature                       none (default)
    fetch_chunksize               16k [bytes] (default)
    fetch_maxchunksize            0.25G [bytes] (default)
    first_byte_timeout            60.000 [seconds] (default)
    gzip_buffer                   32k [bytes] (default)
    gzip_level                    6 (default)
    gzip_memlevel                 8 (default)
    h2_header_table_size          4k [bytes] (default)
    h2_initial_window_size        65535b [bytes] (default)
    h2_max_concurrent_streams     100 [streams] (default)
    h2_max_frame_size             16k [bytes] (default)
    h2_max_header_list_size       2147483647b [bytes] (default)
    h2_rx_window_increment        1M [bytes] (default)
    h2_rx_window_low_water        10M [bytes] (default)
    http_gzip_support             on [bool] (default)
    http_max_hdr                  64 [header lines] (default)
    http_range_support            on [bool] (default)
    http_req_hdr_len              8k [bytes] (default)
    http_req_size                 32k [bytes] (default)
    http_resp_hdr_len             8k [bytes] (default)
    http_resp_size                32k [bytes] (default)
    idle_send_timeout             60.000 [seconds] (default)
    listen_depth                  1024 [connections] (default)
    lru_interval                  2.000 [seconds] (default)
    max_esi_depth                 5 [levels] (default)
    max_restarts                  4 [restarts] (default)
    max_retries                   4 [retries] (default)
    max_vcl                       100 (default)
    max_vcl_handling              1 (default)
    nuke_limit                    50 [allocations] (default)
    pcre_match_limit              10000 (default)
    pcre_match_limit_recursion    20 (default)
    ping_interval                 3 [seconds] (default)
    pipe_timeout                  60.000 [seconds] (default)
    pool_req                      10,100,10 (default)
    pool_sess                     10,100,10 (default)
    pool_vbo                      10,100,10 (default)
    prefer_ipv6                   off [bool] (default)
    rush_exponent                 3 [requests per request] (default)
    send_timeout                  600.000 [seconds] (default)
    shm_reclen                    255b [bytes] (default)
    shortlived                    10.000 [seconds] (default)
    sigsegv_handler               on [bool] (default)
    syslog_cli_traffic            on [bool] (default)
    tcp_fastopen                  off [bool] (default)
    tcp_keepalive_intvl           75.000 [seconds] (default)
    tcp_keepalive_probes          9 [probes] (default)
    tcp_keepalive_time            7200.000 [seconds] (default)
    thread_pool_add_delay         0.000 [seconds] (default)
    thread_pool_destroy_delay     1.000 [seconds] (default)
    thread_pool_fail_delay        0.200 [seconds] (default)
    thread_pool_max               3000 [threads]
    thread_pool_min               150 [threads]
    thread_pool_reserve           0 [threads] (default)
    thread_pool_stack             96k [bytes]
    thread_pool_timeout           300.000 [seconds] (default)
    thread_pool_watchdog          60.000 [seconds] (default)
    thread_pools                  4 [pools]
    thread_queue_limit            20 (default)
    thread_stats_rate             10 [requests] (default)
    timeout_idle                  70.000 [seconds]
    timeout_linger                0.050 [seconds] (default)
    vcc_allow_inline_c            off [bool] (default)
    vcc_err_unref                 on [bool] (default)
    vcc_unsafe_path               on [bool] (default)
    vcl_cooldown                  600.000 [seconds] (default)
    vcl_dir                       /etc/varnish:/usr/share/varnish/vcl (default)
    vcl_path                      /etc/varnish:/usr/share/varnish/vcl (default)
    vmod_dir                      /usr/lib64/varnish/vmods (default)
    vmod_path                     /usr/lib64/varnish/vmods (default)
    vsl_buffer                    4k [bytes] (default)
    vsl_mask                      -ObjProtocol,-ObjStatus,-ObjReason,-ObjHeader,-VCL_trace,-WorkThread,-Hash,-VfpAcct,-H2RxHdr,-H2RxBody,-H2TxHdr,-H2TxBody (default)
    vsl_reclen                    255b [bytes] (default)
    vsl_space                     4000M [bytes]
    vsm_free_cooldown             60.000 [seconds] (default)
    vsm_space                     1M [bytes] (default)
    workspace_backend             64k [bytes] (default)
    workspace_client              64k [bytes] (default)
    workspace_session             0.50k [bytes] (default)
    workspace_thread              2k [bytes] (default)

